# Unity: 'Jostick.inputVector' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner using C# and trying to create a touch controller, but when it compiles it gives following error:

> Jostick.inputVector is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Following is the script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.Characters.FirstPerson;

public class CalleAll : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public FixedJoystick MoveJoystick;
    public FixedTouchField TouchField;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        var fps = GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController>();

        fps.RunAxis = MoveJoystick.inputVector;
        fps.mouseLook.LookAxis=TouchField.TouchDist;
    }
}
```

And this is the script file.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class FixedJoystick : Joystick
{
    public Vector2 joystickPosition = Vector2.zero;
    private Camera cam = new Camera();

    void Start()
    {
        joystickPosition = RectTransformUtility.WorldToScreenPoint(cam, background.position);
    }

    public override void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Vector2 direction = eventData.position - joystickPosition;
        ///here it is
        inputVector = (direction.magnitude > background.sizeDelta.x / 2f) ? direction.normalized : direction / (background.sizeDelta.x / 2f);
        ClampJoystick();
        handle.anchoredPosition = (inputVector * background.sizeDelta.x / 2f) * handleLimit;
    }

    public override void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnDrag(eventData);
    }

    public override void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        inputVector = Vector2.zero;
        handle.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend referring to instance members with the `this.` keyword to avoid confusing `TitleCase` identifiers for public members with type names (i.e. static member references).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because the class `Joystick` has a `protected` member already named `inputVector` - you cannot use it from within types other than its subclasses (which is why `FixedJoystick` can use it, but not `CalleAll`, as `CalleAll` does not derive from `Joystick`).

You can make the data available to consumers by creating a readonly property that exposes the data:

```
class FixedJoystick : Joystick
{
    public Vector2 InputVector
    {
        get { return this.inputVector; }
    }
}

class CalleAll : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        var fps = GetComponent<RigidbodyFirstPersonController>();
        fps.RunAxis = this.MoveJoystick.InputVector;
    }
}
```